# How to create a directory in current project like src/main/java/directiory in Android?

Tags: android

I have tried this code but could not able create a directory and ***given an error No such file or Directory and Unable to create a directory***

I.g Project Location : d:/DemoApp/app/src/main/java/..

String dirPath = "src/main/java/folder";

```
    try {
    File newDirectory = new File(dirPath);

    boolean isCreated = newDirectory.mkdirs();
    if (isCreated) {

            Log.d("1. Successfully created directories",
                    newDirectory.getCanonicalPath());

    } else if (newDirectory.exists()) {
        Log.d("1. Directory path already exist,
                newDirectory.getCanonicalPath());
    } else {
        Log.d("1. Unable to create directory",""+ isCreated);
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You can't. The project is on your developer machine. Your app is on Android. These are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that's correct, app and project are on different location.

Answer (score 0):

As the path include creation of multiple directories mkdir doesn't work.

Use

```
newDirectory.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Gradle` there, for example:

```
mkdir("${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/java/directory")
```

also see [working with files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is really an Android question, since you are using `System.out.print` there, it is not the way Android logging works ... But assuming that you are building an Android app, this would be my opinion:

Your main problem is, that you are trying to create a directory in you source files. BUT these files are only available on your computer and not the device later. Your .apk gets compiled out of these files and folders and has nothing to do with "app/src/main/java" later.

If you want to create and use a directory during runtime of your app, you have to create it either in the internal storage (the folder your app gets installed on the device), or external storage (sd card, or storage acting like sdcard even if its build in).

Please read following manuals for each option:

[Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

[Save files on device storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files)

Comment: well ... then this question is not really Android related (maybe java). And in the case author is trying to create a directory on his pc, then the information is not enough to know what the aim is and how it should be created (otherwise a simple creation of the folder can be done in UI of the IDE / OS / console etc.